# Connect with facebook within Angular 7 app

Tags: angular, facebook, facebook-javascript-sdk, angular7

I'm trying to add a facebook login to my angular app.

I used the facebook javascript sdk and it worked a little. On Android, the login page came up and I entered my credentials. But when I clicked the login button, nothing happened. After reopening the app, I was logged in.
--> Not the best case

On iOS, the login page did not even open.

The implementation:

```
( window as any ).fbAsyncInit = () => {
    FB.init({
        appId: 'myAppId',
        xfbml: true,
        version: 'v2.10'
    });
};

const id = 'facebook-jssdk';
const ref = document.getElementsByTagName('script')[0];

if (document.getElementById(id)) {
    return;
}

const js = document.createElement('script');
js.id = id;
js.async = true;
js.src = '//connect.facebook.net/de_DE/sdk.js';

ref.parentNode.insertBefore(js, ref)
```

On button click:

```
FB.login((loginResponse) => {
    console.log(loginResponse);
}, {scope: 'public_profile'});
```

---

Then I tried to implement it manually using this guide https://developers.facebook.com/docs/facebook-login/manually-build-a-login-flow
My problem here is that the redirect url will be opened within the browser that opened the facebook login page. But I need to go back to my app.

Does someone has experience with this? What's the right/best way to implement the facebook login?

Comment: Well you are only logging something to console in the FB.login callback function … so what more did you expect to happen?

Comment: I should go back. In my Chrome browser it works fine.
I did it like this example (without fetching user data):
https://developers.facebook.com/docs/javascript/examples

Comment: Go back to where? And triggered by what? If you want to redirect somewhere else on successful login - then you need to implement that, in the callback function.

Comment: When I call "FB.login" it opens a page with the login fields (http://m.facebook.com/...). After clicking "Login" on that page, it should go back from where it came from (or whatever I added in my facebook app under developer.facebook.com).
I don't know how I could force it going back to my app.
How could I implement that?

Comment: This is the client-side login flow, that doesn’t “go back” anywhere. The popup closes, and the callback function gets called - that’s it, everything else you want to happen afterwards is _your_ responsibility to implement. Redirecting back somewhere is something that only happens with the server-side login flow.

Comment: Ah ok. Thanks for the explanation. Then the problem is that the popup doesn't close...

Answer (score 0):

I avoided this problem by using the Ionic native plugin https://ionicframework.com/docs/native/facebook/

It uses the cordova-plugin-facebook4.
https://github.com/jeduan/cordova-plugin-facebook4

The native solution works so smooth!